# box2d collision groups

Tags: box2d, collision

does anyone know whether bodies only collide when (body1.categoryBits & body2.maskBits) && (body1.maskBits & body2.categoryBits) ?
 or do they already collide when (body1.categoryBits & body2.maskBits) || (body1.maskBits & body2.categoryBits) ?

Answer (score 31):

If anyone is still looking for more explanations, I made a detailed tutorial here :
http://aurelienribon.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/

[image]

Answer (score 15):

From the Box2D [manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#d0e845):

> **6.2.3. Filtering**
>
> Collision filtering is a system for
>   preventing collision between shapes.
>   For example, say you make a character
>   that rides a bicycle. You want the
>   bicycle to collide with the terrain
>   and the character to collide with the
>   terrain, but you don't want the
>   character to collide with the bicycle
>   (because they must overlap). Box2D
>   supports such collision filtering
>   using categories and groups.
>
> Box2D supports 16 collision
>   categories. For each shape you can
>   specify which category it belongs to.
>   You also specify what other categories
>   this shape can collide with. For
>   example, you could specify in a
>   multiplayer game that all players
>   don't collide with each other and
>   monsters don't collide with each
>   other, but players and monsters should
>   collide. This is done with masking
>   bits. For example:
>
> ```
> playerShapeDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0002;
> monsterShapeDef.filter.categoryBits = 0x0004;
> playerShape.filter.maskBits = 0x0004;
> monsterShapeDef.filter.maskBits = 0x0002;
> ```
>
> Collision groups let you specify an
>   integral group index. You can have all
>   shapes with the same group index
>   always collide (positive index) or
>   never collide (negative index). Group
>   indices are usually used for things
>   that are somehow related, like the
>   parts of a bicycle. In the following
>   example, shape1 and shape2 always
>   collide, but shape3 and shape4 never
>   collide.
>
> ```
> shape1Def.filter.groupIndex = 2;
> shape2Def.filter.groupIndex = 2;
> shape3Def.filter.groupIndex = -8;
> shape4Def.filter.groupIndex = -8;
> ```
>
> Collisions between shapes of different
>   group indices are filtered according
>   the category and mask bits. In other
>   words, group filtering has higher
>   precendence than category filtering.

Answer (score 12):

This is the way I've understood how maskBits and categoryBits work. 
Let's say you have 3 objects : objectA, objectB and objectC.

Define for each object a category :

objectA.categoryBits = 0x0002;
objectB.categoryBits = 0x0004;
objectC.categoryBits = 0x0008;

Then, set the maskBits, which define the collisions rules for each categoryBits :

-> objectA collide with everyone (0xFFFF) and (&) not(~) objectB (0x0004)
objectA.maskBits = 0xFFFF & ~0x0004;

-> objectB collide with objectA (0x0002) or (|) objectC (0x0008) but no one else
objectB.maskBits = 0x0002 | 0x0008;

-> objectC collide with objectA (0x0002) but no one else
objectC.maskBits = 0x0002;

I don't know if this is correct, but it worked for me.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source of Box2d, it shows that if the fixtures belong to different groups (or the groups are 0) then the catgory and masks are compared as follows:

```
    bool collide = (filterA.maskBits & filterB.categoryBits) != 0 && 
                   (filterA.categoryBits & filterB.maskBits) != 0;
```

So it looks like fixture only collide if the collision is allowed by both fixtures' masks.  (IE: AND logic)

Answer (score 0):

I have used walls and many players (our Player and enemies). My player and enemies collides with walls but don't collide with each other. I have done like this and it worked. You have to set the groupIndex to negative value for the objects not to collide with each other. Define the fixtures like this.

```
    /* The categories. */
public static final short CATEGORYBIT_WALL = 1;
public static final short CATEGORYBIT_PLAYERS = 2;

/* And what should collide with what. */
public static final short MASKBITS_WALL = CATEGORYBIT_WALL + CATEGORYBIT_PLAYERS;

public static final FixtureDef WALL_FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f, false, CATEGORYBIT_WALL, MASKBITS_WALL, (short)0);
public static final FixtureDef PLAYERS_FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f, false, CATEGORYBIT_PLAYERS, MASKBITS_WALL, (short)-1);
```

and apply to your bodies.

```
AnimatedSprite player, enemy;
Body playerBody, enemyBody;

player= new AnimatedSprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2,     this.playerRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
playerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, player,     BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYERS_FIXTURE_DEF);   
this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player, playerBody, true, false));

enemy= new AnimatedSprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/4, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, this.enemyRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

enemyBody= PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, enemy, BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYERS_FIXTURE_DEF);
this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(enemy, enemyBody, true, false));
```