# How can I make a body not collide with other bodies sometimes?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

How can I make a body not collide with other bodies sometimes? I have this body that I want it to collide with all bodies unless I specify then it should collide with no bodies. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try using collision filtering:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936935/box2d-collision-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collision filtering is a way to go, especially for your purpose, because you can set filter for certain fixture on the run time, to enable or disable collision detection whenever you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

you can set isSenor() to true

bodyDef.isSensor = true;

"set isSensor() to true when you want to know when objects will collide without triggering a collision response. "