# How to migrate body from current world to another

Tags: java, libgdx

I Currently have a game where you need to switch "realms" and I need to find a way to move Body's from one realm to another. Here is how I am doing it for the player (Each Level has n realms and each realm has Box2D Body's) This is the Level class:

```
public class Level {

private Array<Realm> realms;
private Array<Player> players;
private Realm currentRealm;
private int realmIndex = 0;

InputReciever inputReciever;
private CollisionReciever collisionReciever;
public Level(){

    realms = new Array<Realm>();
    realms.add(new Realm("Realm1"));
    realms.add(new Realm("Realm2"));
    currentRealm = realms.get(realmIndex);

    players = new Array<Player>();
    for(Realm realm : realms){
        players.add(new Player(new Vector2(2, 3)));
        players.get(players.size - 1).createBody(realm.getWorld());
    }
    BoxEntity entity = new BoxEntity(new Vector2(2, 1), new Vector2(1, .25f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(currentRealm.getWorld());

    entity = new BoxEntity(new Vector2(5, 1.75f), new Vector2(1, .25f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(currentRealm.getWorld());

    entity = new BoxEntity(new Vector2(5.5f, .75f), new Vector2(.5f, .15f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(currentRealm.getWorld());

    entity = new BoxEntity(new Vector2(7, -1.75f), new Vector2(1, .15f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(currentRealm.getWorld());

    entity = new BoxEntity(new Vector2(6, -.25f), new Vector2(1, .15f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(realms.get(1).getWorld());

    entity= new BoxEntity(new Vector2(3, 1), new Vector2(1, .5f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(realms.get(1).getWorld());

    entity= new BoxEntity(new Vector2(3, -1), new Vector2(1, .25f), BodyType.StaticBody);
    entity.createBody(realms.get(1).getWorld());


    inputReciever = new InputReciever(players.get(realmIndex), this);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputReciever);

    collisionReciever = new CollisionReciever();
    collisionReciever.setPlayer(players.get(realmIndex));
    currentRealm.getWorld().setContactListener(collisionReciever);
}

private Player tmpPlayer;
public void switchRealm(){
    tmpPlayer = players.get(realmIndex);
    if(realmIndex < realms.size - 1){
        realmIndex ++;
    }else
        realmIndex = 0;


    currentRealm = realms.get(realmIndex);
    currentRealm.getWorld().setContactListener(collisionReciever);
    inputReciever.setPlayer(players.get(realmIndex));
    //this transforms the player in the list to the position of the original
    players.get(realmIndex).retainState(tmpPlayer);
    collisionReciever.setPlayer(players.get(realmIndex));
}

public void render(OrthographicCamera camera){
    currentRealm.render(camera);
}

public void update(OrthographicCamera camera){
    camera.position.set(players.get(realmIndex).getBody().getTransform().getPosition(), 0);

    currentRealm.update(camera);

    players.get(realmIndex).update();
}
```

}

The way I switch Realms causes a studder in the game, before I continue, here is the method "retainState();" for player

```
public void retainState(Player player){
    ((Body) bodyObjects.get(BodyReferences.BODY)).setTransform(player.getBody().getPosition(), player.getBody().getAngle());
    ((Body) bodyObjects.get(BodyReferences.BODY)).setLinearVelocity(player.getBody().getLinearVelocity());
}
```

My question is, is there a way to place a body inside of another world without recreating it? I am using multiple worlds so I may change the rayhandler effects and for the level editor, so basically, I need to do this with multiple worlds.

**Question:** Is there a way to move a Body from one world to another World without using bit filtering?

I am fully aware of bit filtering but this is the way my dev team set up the UML so I must follow design to the best of my ability for now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple worlds I'd recommend [collision filtering](https://aurelienribon.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/) by [groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936935/box2d-collision-groups). Changing a group is just changing one parameter instead of copying a whole body from one world into another and I expect it to be much more performant.

> Groups should be used instead of categories and masks when you only
>   need to disable collisions between objects of a same category.